# Stopping power diagram

Tags: particle-physics

I'm currently looking at this figure, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. If I'm not mistaken, the energy loss of the muon (This is a muon that penetrates copper) is on the y-axis. But does that just mean, that if my muon has energy of around 0.5 GeV, then it has a stopping power around 2 MeV cm2/g (Minimum ionization), which means it loses that amount of energy pr. cm2/g?

To me that just seems a bit "linear". I've seen curves, like with proton therapy, where protons lose most of their energy at some distance inside the material, and then loses minimum energy in the start. But can that even translate into this figure, or am I missing something here?

[image: Stopping power]

Comment: You are correct that the total stopping of a 0.5 GeV muon is about 2 MeV-cm2/g.  As it loses energy, the stopping will start to increase, peaking when the muon has an energy of about 1 MeV.  For protons the curves (on the same energy scale) would not be all that different - the nuclear losses dominate at low energy (say under 10keV), and electronic losses increase at higher energies, then roll over eventually (no longer velocity matching), then the radiative losses will kick up again at really high energies.

Comment: So from this, can you actually tell anything about the range and energy loss of a proton into a person (As an example). I mean, as I stated, I've seen diagrams where you see that the proton (As in particle therapy) loses a small fraction of its energy until it reach a certain point, and then deposit most of it's energy. Can that diagram/graph be made from anything in this figure, or is that two separate ways to make diagrams?

Comment: @JonCuster can we say that at minimum ionization inelastic nuclear reactions dominate the energy loss and there is no Bragg Peak?

Answer (score 1):

To explore the contributions of electronic (ion-electron scattering) and nuclear (ion-target atom) stopping, you can look at SRIM, available for download free from srim.org.  This program was create by Ziegler, Ziegler, and Biersack ages ago and has been update by them since (yes, the same Ziegler as on a label on your graph above). Note that SRIM does not deal with the radiative effects at very high particle energy - it is/was mainly concerned with modeling ion implantation effects, not relativistic high energy particle physics.

Calculating the stopping power/ranges for protons in water, it is readily seen that the electronic stopping dominates nuclear interactions along almost all of the proton path length (again, I'm ignoring radiative contributions).  A few examples are given here (stopping units of MeV/(mg/cm2)):

```
Proton energy    dE/dx (elec)  dE/dx (nucl)  Range +/- straggle (um)
10 MeV              4.657E-2      2.700E-5   1200 +/- 54
1 MeV               2.402E-1      2.090E-4   26.55 +/- 1.16 
100 keV             8.252E-1      1.476E-3   1.43 +/- 0.11
10 keV              4.283E-1      8.66E-3    0.26 +/- 0.07
1 keV               1.447E-1      3.364E-2   0.03 +/- 0.02
100 eV              4.577E-2      6.354E-2   0.004 +/- 0.004
```

So, for protons into water, the peak of the overall stopping is near 100keV, and almost all of that stopping is electronic.  Only at very low energies does the nuclear stopping finally exceed the electronic.  This is why protons have a pretty sharp end of range - the electronic stopping is a very smooth stopping as the proton scatters off of lots of electrons, losing very little energy each time.  The nuclear stopping is a more violent event (larger momentum transfer), but really only happens at the end of range.  So, the proton transfers energy to target *atoms* only at the end of range.  Energy is being continually lost to electron scattering along the whole trajectory (in varying amounts depending on the proton energy at that point).

That last bit is important - you can get the energy loss at a given energy, but as the proton loses energy, you have to re-evaluate what the energy loss is at that new energy. If you are above the energy loss peak, a little more proton energy gives you a much longer range until it finally slows closer to the peak energy loss.  (Note that a 10MeV proton has a range of 1.2 millimeters, while a 1 MeV proton goes only 26 microns, and a 100keV proton about 1.5 microns.)